# Changing A-Frame scene 3 times breaks COORS

Tags: aframe, webvr

When hovering over another entity my location.scene_img_url value changes (s3 location). After the second change, aframe fails with a COORS error.

```
<a-scene>
  <a-sky ng-click="print()" src="{{location.scene_img_url}}" crossorigin="anonymous"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS error when I load image from another server inside a-sky tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001934/cors-error-when-i-load-image-from-another-server-inside-a-sky-tag)

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn My issue is different. I get the initial resource successfully. After using Gaze event with angular to trigger a new src value I see a COORS error.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you find this issue for yourself. Here is how I worked around.

Rather than using an inline url which points to an external asset (s3 bucket url). Use the aws-sdk to make a request for the image. Image will be received as a Byte array. Convert byte array to base64 and render.

Heres a look at how I did it:

```
  this.getImage = function(location, assetName) {

  var creds = {
    Bucket: 'YOURBUCKET-URL',
    Key: "RELATIVE PATH"
  }

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var image;
    creds.Key += location + "/" + assetName;

    s3.getObject(creds, function(err, data) {
      if (!err) {
        image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + encode(data.Body);
        resolve(image)
      } else {
        console.log(err)
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Here is a really awesome way to convert Byte array to base64:

```
 function encode(buffer) {
  var binary = '';
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  var len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }

  return window.btoa(binary);
}
```