# Panorama won't load in AFrame 360 Image script when hosted on work website backend

Tags: aframe, 360-panorama

I am working on hosting a 360 panorama for work, I have got it to work using AFrame 360 Image when the file is hosted on Imgur, but I need to try get it to host off my works website as to support a larger file size and ease of access. Currently the script loads in but then no image appears, this occurs for any image hosted on the website. Why would this be?

I have tried files of all different sizes and extensions, none of them load inside the script despite being accessible through direct link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <a-scene>
      <a-sky src="https://mapping.hdc.govt.nz/photos/LowStitch.jpg" rotation="0 0 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected it to work the same as when using the image hosted off Imgur, however all I get is a white screen with the VR logo in the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the console logs -

> Access to image at 'https://mapping.hdc.govt.nz/photos/LowStitch.jpg' ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-> Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

it shows its a CORS (**C**ross-**o**rigin **R**esource **S**haring) error. It means the server is not serving the files with a CORS header for `aframe.io` - therefore denying the resource. Try putting the website at the same directory as the photos. Or contact the server administrator about the header.

For details on CORS - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001934/cors-error-when-i-load-image-from-another-server-inside-a-sky-tag) is an explicit anwser on CORS in aframe by H.Pauwelyn.

Answer (score 0):

Asset needs CORS headers for it to be loaded cross origin from your web host: https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load